# A application Post on User's walls using Facebook PHP registration API?

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth

basically we are using facebook registration API for our website user registration and we are storing user data in our database with access token, at the time of registration,we want the user allow us the wall post permission.So what we will do..?

Here is the code we are using to try to launch the dialog popup:

```
<iframe src="facebook.com/plugins/… echo $redirect_uri;?>&       &cope=publish_stream,offline_access&fields=[ {'name':'name'},
{'name':'first_name'}, {'name':'last_name'}, {'name':'email'}, {'name':'gender'},     
{'name':'birthday'}, {'name':'password'} 
]"scrolling="auto"frameborder="no"style="border:none"allowTransparency="tru‌e"   
width="570"height="800"> </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your token is granted only for the permissions you specifically requested when you requested the the application be authorized by the user.  To be able to post to a users wall, you need to ask the user to authorize the appropriate permissions.

Here is the facebook reference for requesting these permissions:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#adding

Depending on your app, you'll need to ask for either/both `publish_actions` or `publish_stream` when you get initial authentication from the user.

Comment: Sir actully we want the code,that how to show the allow popup on users wall using this facebook API?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Sir this is my code..
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=<?php echo $redirect_uri;?>&
    scope=publish_stream,offline_access&fields=[
     {'name':'name'}, 
     {'name':'first_name'},
     {'name':'last_name'}, 
     {'name':'email'},
     {'name':'gender'},
     {'name':'birthday'},
     {'name':'password'}
     ]"scrolling="auto"frameborder="no"style="border:none"allowTransparency="true"width="570"height="800">
    </iframe>

but it's not showing the popup..

Comment: Facebook recommends using javascript to login and authenticate users for any web app.  the documentation links have code examples on how to do this, and I believe there is even a sample application in the documentation that you can download that has source code you can work from to do so.  The purpose of stack overlow is not for me to write your code for you, but to help you understand what you're doing wrong.

Comment: when i m using user_photos on scope section it support,but when i am using other like email,then a blank page displayed..